# Ajax запрос,не заходит в success

Tags: php, ajax, json

Запрос:

```js
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: "text="+text,
        url: "text.php",
        dataType: "json",
        error: function(){
          alert('Load was failed.');
      },
        success: function(){
          alert('Load was performed.');
      }
 });
```

Скрипт обработки:

```php
<?php
$text = $_POST ["text"];
$file = 'text.txt';
$current = file_get_contents($file);
file_put_contents($file, $text);
?>
```

В файл все записывается. Но обрабатывается error,а не success.
Что не так?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dataType: "json",` указывает вызову, что ответ будет в формате JSON. Если при разборе ответа произошла ошибка, будет вызван обработчик `error`

Добавьте в свой файл вывод корректного JSON объекта, как минимум

```
...
file_put_contents($file, $text);
echo '{}';
?>
```

Comment: спасибо=)не заметил этот тайп((слепошарый......